# google sheets. how do i make a table that collects the content of cell C20 from a lot of different sheets in the same file?

Tags: google-sheets

I am building a solar-system. Artifexian (a youtuber) has created a google sheet that calculates all the necessary values I would need to start mapping the system. I want to get the albedo value from each of the planets I create and put all of them in a single table. All the calculations for a specific body are on a sheet named after it's name.

The reference i have is: ='PLANET Sphe'!C20 I can change the "PLANET Sphe" part manually but the work involved starts to add up when I start creating hundreds of moons and kuiper belt objects. And will also need tables for the semi-major axis and the radius.

Is there a way for me to write the planet names in one column. Then in the next column over have the reference pull the sheet name from the text in the first?

Comment: Not clear but `INDIRECT()` function may help.

Comment: @Harun24hr probably

Comment: Can you share a sample workbook with us?

Comment: @Harun24hr my answer hopefully makes it clear

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MwRBNKf0ux40sL2Cr8KxUzZXbxdgW0r9KZQPqbjZNbo/edit?usp=sharing
I am talking about the rightmost sheet named "APPARENT SIZE & BRIGHTNESS" in cell D37.

The following formula worked for me.

`=INDIRECT("'PLANET "&B37&"'!C20")`

It is concatenated from 3 parts

`"PLANET "`
This is the first part and is added as a string. It is the first part of the Sheet name and the same for all planets made.

`&B37&`
This concatenates the string of part one to whatever is written in cell B37. And it concatenates it with the 2nd & to part three.

`'!C20`
Also put in as a string. The '! finishes the reference to which sheet is to be looked at. Then cell C20 on that sheet contains the displayed output.

the computer resolves it as follows:

`=INDIRECT("'PLANET "&B37&"'!C20")`

`=INDIRECT("'PLANET "&Whesm&"'!C20")`

`=INDIRECT('PLANET Whesm'!C20)`

`='PLANET Whesm'!C20` output cell C20 located on sheet 'PLANET Whesm'

Comment: If this is not an answer, update your question